# Append a String to the end of the existing String with specific position in a text file in Java

Tags: bufferedreader, filereader, randomaccessfile

Exp -
In a text file we have the following topics with some description.

---

**#Repeat the annotation**

It is the major topic for .....

**#Vector analysis**

It covers all the aspects of sequential....

**#Cloud Computing**

Create header accounts for all the users

---

We have to add / append new Tags to the Topics in specific line
For exp-

**#Repeat the annotation #Maven build**

**#Cloud Computing #SecondYear**

File f = new File("/user/imp/value/GSTR.txt");

```
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
    Object fr1;
    while((fr1 = fr.read()) != null) {

        if(fr1.equals("#Repeat the annotation")) {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f,true);
        fw.write("#Maven build");
        fw.close();


        }
    }
```

****** #Maven is getting added to the last line of the text file but not at the specific position next to the topic

Answer (score 0):

The output is written to the file GSTR_modified.txt. The code along with an example input file is also available [here](https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/Sam). The code in the github repository reads the file "input.txt" and writes to the file "output.txt".

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Create a list to store the file content.
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // Store the file content in the list. Each line becomes an element in the list.
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/user/imp/value/GSTR.txt""))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(line);
        }
    }
    // Iterate the list of lines.
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        // line is the element at the index i.
        String line = list.get(i);
        // Check if a line is equal to "#Repeat the annotation"
        if (line.contains("#Repeat the annotation")){
            // Set the list element at index i to the line itself concatenated with
            // the string " #Maven build".
            list.set(i,line.concat(" #Maven build"));
        }
        // Same pattern as above.
        if (line.contains("#Cloud Computing")){
            list.set(i,line.concat(" #SecondYear"));
        }
    }
    // Write the contents of the list to a file.
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("GSTR_modified.txt");
    for(String str: list) {
        // Append newline character \n to each element
        // and write it to file.
        writer.write(str+"\n");
    }
    writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is any space before "#Repeat the annotation" then "  #Maven build" is not getting appended. Can we have any option to remove space dependency , i.e Any where is a line "#Repeat the annotation" is present "  #Maven build" will get appended

Comment: You can use the method contains of the class String to check if a line contains "#Repeat the annotation". See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html. Search for "contains". The string " #Repeat the annotation" for example contains "#Repeat the annotation".

Comment: I changed the conditionals in the if statements to (line.contains("...")). This removes what you call space dependency. Please upvote my answer if it is useful for you.

Comment: Michael_H --Its working as expected.Thanks for the update

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.